# How find out reasoning behind delete vote?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

I have an answer that has been voted up to a reasonable level, which I take to mean it was a positive contribution.  But there has been one vote to delete.  How do I figure out the reason for a vote to delete?  There are no comments.

[Is there a term that describes straight 8ths / 16ths vs swing?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/34522/is-there-a-term-that-describes-straight-8ths-16ths-vs-swing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sentence answers are frowned upon. That was the case with your answer pre edit. Chances are good that was what the problem was.

Answer (score 5):

Without a comment to tell you, you don't know. All you can tell is that someone disagreed with the post, or the way it was written.

Having read the post, I would probably have to agree with the delete vote - compare your post with Dom's post, which provides a bit of explanation. Yours seems to be more of comment.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dr said, you can't see the person(s) who cast the delete votes. This goes for all the votes here on the SE sites. You cannot see who upvoted/downvoted a post. Not even mods can see.

Comment: I have no interest in the identity of the deletion proponent -- I was just scratching my head about the reason.  I went with Mayhem's conjecture, that the answer was too much like a comment, and have tried to make it more like an answer.